# Getting Assembly GUID programmatically that matches that in Visual studio solution file (*.sln)

Tags: c#, .net

I want to get an assembly GUID that is used in a Visual Studio solution file (*.sln), like below:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
 #Visual Studio 2010

Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "ClassLibrary3", "..\ClassLibrary3\ClassLibrary3.csproj", "{5B402A1B-18B1-4D88-804A-BC0E58EF3730}"
EndProject
```

I tried the code below, all **failed**:

```
  //attempt 1: 
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(grandProject.AssemblyFilePath);
var id = assembly.GetType().GUID.ToString();

    //attempt 2
var attribute = (GuidAttribute)assembly.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(GuidAttribute), true)[0];
var id = attribute.Value;
```

Any idea?

Comment: That's the project GUID. It is used by Visual Studio internally and is not related to the generated assemblies in any way.

Comment: how to get it via C# if possible?

Comment: @Pingpong Why? It's not in the DLL, it's in the csproj and sln *only*.

Comment: I am working on a console app to change a project that uses dll references to project references. Thus, I need to edit the .sln, and *.csproj files programmatically.

Comment: I found it, it is the project file. (*.csproj).

Answer (score 0):

The assembly guid used in *.sln file is in *.csproj file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <PropertyGroup>

    <ProjectGuid>{5B402A1B-18B1-4D88-804A-BC0E58EF3730}</ProjectGuid>

  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: So how does this answer your own question? How did you get the GUID programmatically?

Comment: by parsing the xml, and get the GUID grogrammatically. Otherwise, There might be APIs from VS.